# How to find a symmetry group of a system if all the symmetry transformations do not obey closure and don't form a group?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, symmetry, group-theory

For instance, consider a system with $p_x$ and $p_z$ orbitals at the vertices of a square (on xy-plane). A square by itself would have $D_4$ symmetry. However, because of the $p_x$ orbital; the $90^\circ$ rotation ($C_4$) and $270^\circ$ rotation ($C_4^{-1}$) are no longer symmetry operations. Now the rest of the $D_4$ members do preserve the symmetry, but do not form a group since the subset is not closed.

How does one go about formulating a symmetry group for cases like these?

Comment: Never saw a rotation denoted with $r$. Normally, 90° and 270° rotations are denoted with $C_4$ and $C_4^{-1}$ (or $3C_4),$ respectfully. This should give you a hint when you look up the point group using a character table. $r$ and $r^3$ in your context would refer to the distance and volume, respectfully.

Comment: Orbitals are not relevant to molecular symmetry. Only atoms are. Are the atoms at the four corners of the square identical? If so, then 90 degree rotation does return the original molecule.

Comment: @andselisk Sorry about the issue with notations, I've fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I am mildly confused: a square should be $D_\mathrm{4h}$, surely?

Comment: @Andrew Actually this is sort of a hypothetical problem from physics. It's not really a molecule, and I'm considering a system that contains hypothetical atoms with only $p_x$ and $p_z$ like orbitals at the four vertices. I'm afraid a $C_4$ rotation will turn $p_x$ into $p_y$ breaking the symmetry.

Comment: The symmetry transformations **do** obey closure and do form a group, otherwise they are not symmetry transformations.

Comment: If what you have in mind is something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZTV7.jpg, then it appears to me to be $D_\mathrm{2h}$.

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks for pointing out the typo, I actually meant $D_4$ (Dihedral_4 group). I have learned group theory as a topic in mathematics and physics mostly, and I'm a beginner in crystal symmetry and point-groups etc. I think perhaps the Dihedral_4 group of the square is called D4h in the Schoenflies notation (..?)

Comment: @orthocresol Thank you so much! I indeed meant what you mentioned in the image. I'm going to look into $D_{2h}$ point group.

Comment: "I'm afraid a C4 rotation will turn px into py breaking the symmetry" My point was that atomic orbitals cannot "break symmetry" because they are not considered when determining the symmetry group of a molecule. If you make a molecular orbital out of a combination of atomic orbitals, then you need to ensure that the molecular orbital is sym or antisym w.r.t. one (but not necessarily) all of the operations of the determined group.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, so I'm not entirely sure what notation you're using ($D_4$ sounded like Schönflies to me), but I'm sure you can figure out the equivalent.

In general I agree with Andrew's point that molecular symmetry is determined by atomic positions and not orbitals. But at least to me as of now, this seems to be a thought exercise more than anything (after all, no real atom has only two p-orbitals), so I'll play along. In Schönflies notation your system would be labelled $D_\mathrm{2h}$. The three $C_2$ axes and three mirror planes are illustrated below. I left out the identity operation $E$ and the centre of inversion $i$.

[image: Symmetry operations]

Comment: +1, orthocresol, What software did you use to draw these pictures? Is it a pen used PowerPoint?

Comment: @M.Farooq, stylus on tablet, more specifically Apple Pencil + iPad Pro using the Notability app (starting to sound like an Apple commercial so I had better stop here...)

Comment: Figure looks nice! I feel a common stylus in PowerPoint should also be able to draw similar figures. Don't have these Apple products.

Comment: Yep, I've done similar things in PowerPoint before on my iPad, so I don't think special software is necessary. As far as hardware goes, there are many on the market nowadays.